# Перебор в нескольких процессах

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

**Задача**: Программа должна перебрать все строки из 'wordlixt.txt' и подставлять их в функцию **brute()** в **10** процессах.

Но у меня в **консоль** выводится почему-то **6** раз по '...'.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os


string_with_pass = 'scooby'


def brute(password):
    if password == string_with_pass:
        print(f'[+] Found: {password}')
        os._exit(0)
    else:
        print(f'...')


def get_pass():
    passwords = open('wordlist.txt', 'r').readlines()
    for line in passwords:
        password = line.strip()
        return password


def main():
    with Pool(10) as p:
        p.map(brute, get_pass())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Вангую, что первая строка файла имеет 6 символов :D `get_pass()` возвращает первую строку файла, а в `p.map(brute, get_pass())` вы на каждый символ вызываете `brute`. А попробуйте не функцию использовать, а генератор -- в `get_pass`, замените `return password` на `yield password`

Comment: @gil9red Появилось проблема: Когда программа перебирает от 2 процессов одновременно, то почему-то она не доходит до конца файла и начинается бесконечный цикл

Comment: Когда запускаю программу, то в диспетчере успешно отображаются все 10 процессов, но потом они сами закрываются и начинается бесконечный цикл

Comment: Странно... Возможно, проблема в генераторе.. перепишите функцию, чтобы она возвращала список: `def get_pass(): return [line.strip() for line in open('wordlist.txt', 'r').readlines()]`

Comment: Всё равно застревает

Comment: @gil9red Странно... Запустил пару раз повторно и успешно перебрал всё

Comment: Но почему он работает через раз?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать конкурентно запустить:

```
import asyncio


async def brute(password):
    string_with_pass = 'brutit_ploho'
    if password == string_with_pass:
        return f'Found: {password}'
    else:
        return '...'


async def main(future):
    passwords = await future
    for result in asyncio.as_completed([brute(pswd) for pswd in passwords]):
        print(await result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    file = open('asd', 'r')
    passwords_list = file.read().splitlines()

    future = loop.create_future()
    future.set_result(passwords_list)

    asyncio.run(main(future))
```

Comment: Я пока что совсем не понимаю модуль asyncio. Не могли бы вы привести пример с модулем multiprocessing или threading к примеру

Comment: gil9red в комменте к вашему вопросу уже указал в чем ошибка, я просто предложил чуть другой способ, более эффективный, на мой взгляд

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'`

Comment: На Python 3.7.2 писал код, на предыдущих версиях может не работать